# wp_enqueue_script and php scripts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have some javascript in my footer that are only being dropped in if they pass a php check. Due to some page optimisations I would like to enqueue these scripts. I tried to enqueue the php scripts like so:

```
function add_base_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(get_template_directory_uri() . '/base-scripts.php');
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_base_scripts');
```

But I'm not seeing any of the scripts from base-scripts.php being put into the page. It's definately the correct directory which makes me think its a problem with the scripts being in a php file. I haven't found anything online as to if you can use a php file or not. Can someone confirm/debunk this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with this, we came to the conclusion that you cannot enqueue a php script. We had to use a workaround to solve our problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_base_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script('script-handle',get_template_directory_uri() . '/base-scripts.php');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_base_scripts');
```

You got to add a handle to the enqueue_scripts [more info](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Comment: Just added a handle - same problem. I can't see the scripts from base-scripts.php in the page.

Comment: Oh sorry, i read over the .php part, can't you just change it to include(FILEPATH) instead of enqueuescript?

Comment: We're using enqueue script because of the way the plugin autoptimize picks up scripts. If we just include the scripts there are errors because they get loaded before jQuery.